# How Close to Fecal Matter is Unhealthy

Tags: disease-transmission, lifestyle, environmental-conditions, stools, zoonotic-diseases

I hope this is the appropriate place to ask such a question and I've Googled this thought but have come back empty handed so wanted to run it by the stack exchange community.

Can I catch any diseases or illnesses by merely scooping up dog feces?

Is bending over to scoop up dog poop putting my respiratory system and face too close to fecal matter whereas after scooping it up and disturbing the pile I would now have microscopic ?pathogens? all over my face, neck, clothing, arms etc JUST BY scooping it up and being in such close proximity?

Comment: Anyone care to comment?